# different results between Linq and SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, linq

i don't know why i get different results between this SQL and LINQ
Could you like to tell me why...?

SQL:

```
select distinct top 50 (id) as d_id
from talbe1
where id<>-1
order by d_id  asc;
```

Linq:

```
    IList<int> myResults =
        (from t in dbconn.table1
         where t.id != -1
         orderby t.id ascending
         select t.id
        ).Distinct().Take(50).ToList();

    int callCnt = 0;
    foreach (int row in myResults)
    {
        callCnt++;
        Console.WriteLine(callCnt.ToString() + " " + row.ToString() );
    }
```

The SQL get the results i want,
 but the Linq result is like :

```
1 72662
2 84945
3 264577
4 77655
5 71756
6 76899
7 76719
8 77669
9 152211
10 79168
11 72334
12 71399
13 246031
14 80748
15 77715

.......
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of LINQ to SQL, where the `OrderBy()` must occur after the `Distinct()`, try this:

```
IList<int> myResults =
    (from t in dbconn.table1
     where t.id != -1
     select t.id
    ).Distinct().OrderBy(t => t).Take(50).ToList();
```

Comment: Darn, I missed it by *this* much :P  Quick edit though... should be `.OrderBy(t => t)` since it's an `IEnumerable<int>` at that point.

Comment: That's why I missed out being first answer... I type slower :P

Comment: @Corey - :-) don't answer questions on your phone then, I tried a few weeks back and before I could even type a sentence, three people had submitted answers. LOL

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the way that the `Distinct()` method works.  Unfortunately it can (and usually does) change the order of the items in the list.  You need to order the list *after* calling `Distinct()`.

Try this:

```
IList<int> myResults =
    (
        from t in dbconn.table1
        where t.id != -1
        select t.id
    ).Distinct().OrderBy(i => i).Take(50).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var myResults = dbconn.Table1.Where(e => e.id != -1).Select(e => e.id).Distinct()
         .OrderBy(t => t).Take(50).ToList();
```

Comment: 1. Doesn't work.  2. Doesn't return an `IList<int>`.  3. Doesn't explain *why*.

Comment: sorry, it's fixed now.